# Eigenvalues of the sum of a matrix and its complex conjugate?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two vectors, $\mathbf{u}_{m1} = M^{-1/2} [ 1 \ e^{\jmath m_1\beta} \ e^{\jmath 2 m_1 \beta} \cdots e^{\jmath (M-1) m_1 \beta}]^T$ and
$\mathbf{u}_{m2} = M^{-1/2} [ 1 \ e^{\jmath m_2\beta} \ e^{\jmath 2 m_2 \beta} \cdots e^{\jmath (M-1) m_2 \beta}]^T$,
where $M$ is a positive natural number, $m_1,m_2 \in \{1,2,\cdots, M\}$, $m_1 \neq m_2$, $\beta = 2\pi/M$, $^T$ is the transpose operator, and $\jmath$ is the imaginary unit with $\jmath^2 = -1$.

Based on the simulation result, I found that the matrix $\mathbf{u}_{m1}\mathbf{u}_{m2}^H + \mathbf{u}_{m2}\mathbf{u}_{m1}^H$ always have eigenvalues
$\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = -1$.
I would like to know is there anything special about this matrix???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not a special property of the vectors $u_1,u_2$, since this result can be derived by just imposing orthonormality conditions on them. It is a simple matter to see that the linear combinations $u_1\pm u_2$ are eigenvectors of the proposed matrix since

$$(u_1u_2^\dagger+ u_2u_1^\dagger)(u_1\pm u_2)=\pm (u_1\pm u_2)$$

where here we have used the fact that $|u_1|^2=|u_2|^2=1, ~u_1^H u_2=0$.

Comment: One more question~ In the simulation, the parameter is set to be $M=6$, and there is another vector $\mathbf{d} = [ 1 \ e^{-\jmath \alpha 2\pi} \ e^{-\jmath \alpha 4\pi} \  \cdots  \ e^{-\jmath \alpha (M-1) 2\pi } ]^T$, where $\alpha >0$ is a control parameter. 
I always found that $\mathbf{d}^H (\mathbf{u}_m \mathbf{u}^H_{M-m+1} + \mathbf{u}_{M-m+1}\mathbf{u}^H_m ) \mathbf{d} \approx 0$. Is it a coincidence?

Comment: I'm not sure the expression you wrote is exactly zero for all real $\alpha$ but it definitely is for integer controls. That in combination with a very big vector $M$ and random phase cancellations would probably result in very small values for most of the control parameter values.